# What is an Earcon?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I just stumbled upon the method `TextToSpeech.addEarcon(String, String)` in Android's TTS API.
I actually couldn't find more information on the net, so does anyone know what exactly an earcon is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With an Earcon you can map a Name(Parameter1) to a Soundfile-Path(Parameter2).

I think Earcon is a other form of Icon, like Eye-con => Ear-con => Nose-con and so on :-)
[TextToSpeech.html#addEarcon(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#addEarcon%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Aaaah, okay, thanks :D I would have never thought of "Eye-con"

Comment: How is it different from addSpeech(String, String) then ?

Answer (score 9):

#### Earcon

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earcon

> An earcon is a brief, distinctive sound used to represent a specific event or convey other information. Earcons are a common feature of computer operating systems and applications, ranging from beeping when an error occurs to the customizable sound schemes of Windows 7 that indicate startup, shutdown, and many other events.
>
> The name is a pun on the more familiar term icon in computer interfaces. Icon sounds like "eye-con" and are visual, which inspired D.A. Sumikawa to coin "earcon" as the auditory equivalent in a 1985 article, 'Guidelines for the integration of audio cues into computer user interfaces.'

Here's the article they're talking about:

http://www.osti.gov/energycitations/product.biblio.jsp?osti_id=5475406

#### Earcon Android API

> Adds a mapping between a string of text and a sound file. Use this to add custom earcons.

And [here's the API reference for that method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#addEarcon(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).